# Apache Network Drive Alias

Tags: windows, apache, networking, alias

I've searched through stackoverflow for a similiar problem, but none of the solutions seem to work.

I'm running WAMP and have a network drive `T:\` which I want to use as an alias in Apache. So far I have added:

> Alias /p \\ps-file.server_location.edu\A$
>   < Directory /p>
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
>   < / Directory>

However, whenever I try to access `localhost/p` I get a 403 forbidden message saying `You don't have permission to access /p on this server.` Any suggestions?

I have tried changing the logon settings in services.msc, but this stops apache from starting all together.

EDIT: I also have to enter my login information for the network drive the first time I connect it. Can I somehow give apache my login information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use forward slashes instead of backslashes or escape them all using an additional backslashas well as enclosing the paths in quotes as stated by Xophmeister. Eg:

```
Alias /p "//ps-file.server_location.edu/A$/"
<Directory "//ps-file.server_location.edu/A$/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

or

```
Alias /p "\\\\ps-file.server_location.edu\\A$\\"
<Directory "\\\\ps-file.server_location.edu\\A$\\">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You are correct to use a UNC path unless you create a mapped drive in the user profile being used to run the apache service.

Answer (score 1):

caltor is right , little edit here , you can use `<Directory "/p">` cause it has alias.But
I hate writing network drive in config like `//p...` also

There is another problem occurs here , in this method , you cannot execute exec() or batch file , cannot take the information of directory , open_dir etc cannot return a result , also apache cannot start as a service . To solve that,

First of all download 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx
Extract zip file to C:/sys.
Open cmd , and

```
cd c:/sys (enter)
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

then a new command line appears . All you need

```
net use j: \\lethea\sharedfolder /persistent:yes
```

will ask username and password of lethea pc .
Here is j: the short name of the network drive .
After doing this , in httpd.conf folder
you dont need to create alias or write full network map to Documentroot and directory

```
Documentroot = "j:/mywww"  #referencing \\lethea\sharedfolder\mywww
<Directory "j:/mywww">
```

...

Comment: On Windows 8, I had to run the cmd as a Adminsitrator. If you have a cmd window task on the task bar, right click, then right click Command Prompt, click run as adminsitrator

Answer (score 0):

Why not just alias to T:\, as in `Alias /p T:\`? Otherwise, my guess is that Apache doesn't have the necessary permissions to access the specified UNC (particularly, the `A$` bit is probably screwing things up as it is a special share).

Comment: If I use "T:\" I get a directory not found error, and if I use T:\ apache doesn't even start. The network drive I have mapped also requires a logon which I know plays into this, but I don't know exactly how

Comment: Try `T:/`, instead. You may also need to enquote the path: `"T:/"`.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you will need: 
give permission to the board administrator httpd.exe file 
authenticate the service with an administrator of the User Services pane windows 
leave the httpd.conf file so

DocumentRoot "//192.168.50.2/g/htdocs"

set the ip of the host where the files for this machine name by apache does not recognize