# Install wamp on a network drive (not local)

Tags: wamp

First off all, sorry for my english, i'm french.

Currently, i use wampserver on my local computer (which is connected to the network of the firm i work for) and it runs great. Thanks to the solution provided by Emre Karataşoğlu at the following adress ([Apache Network Drive Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431658/apache-network-drive-alias)), i can scan a directory of the network...
Now, I would like to know if it was possible to install wampserver on the network of my compagny. Indeed, in several weeks, i will lose the administrator privileges i've curently on my XP computer (upgrade to SEVEN) and i will not be able anymore to map the drive.
So i thought the solution would be an installation of wamp directly on the network, on the drive  i want to scan.I hoped to WAMP would "recognized" the (network) drive
(because it is installed on it) and i would not have to map the drive !
But i'm afraid it's not possible. If i install WAMP on the network, i can't run apache service. I get the error "Could not perform service action : le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable". Wamp doesn't know the drive on which it is installed (path i can see in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wampapache, ImagePath).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

JC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simple answer is :- No thats not the way.

Lets talk about what WAMPServer is.

Its a utility that installs Apache, PHP and MySQL onto a computer in a ready to go condition.

What are Apache and MySQL, well of course they are Servers ( software not hardware ).

So if you want to use them they can be installed on any PC in your network and ( with the correct configration ) used by any other PC on the network.

Now if your issue is that your website requires access to a network resource then whatever PC that is running Apache/PHP be that a Big Server PC or your new W7 Desktop, that machine MUST have access to the required network resource.

The solution is to talk with your Administrators and tell them that the PC running WampServer(Apache) must have access to that network resource in order to function.

So they will either have to give you access to it, or install WAMPServer(Apache) on another PC that they have control of and give that PC the required privilages.