# PHP cannot access files/dirs on LAN

Tags: php, wamp, lan

I have found similar questions but the result didn't help me.
I need to access - read, write, list files and dirs on computer in local network but php is not able to find or read it.
I use this code

```
 $scandir = scandir("//192.168.101.22/somedir"); //returns false
```

And errors I got:

> scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory
>
> scandir(//192.168.101.22/somedir): failed to open dir: No such file or directory

I shared this folder on LAN computer with full access for Everyone. When I open this location in Total Commander, there is no problem. Also I created a shared folder on the computer where PHP is located and PHP found this folder. I tried to use backslashes or `file:`, nothing helped me.

PHP version: 5.4.16

Wamp server 2.4

Windows 8.1 (where WAMP is located)

Windos 7 pro (computer on LAN)

Comment: You need to impersonate the windows user to gain access. PHP has a different user than the current user.

Comment: Well, this sounds logical. I found solutions for IIS and fastcgi. Can you help me with impersonate for WAMP?

Comment: If you are using PHP locally, try adding `wwwuser` or `www-user` or which user php uses to create/access files to the Users group. I don't know what'll happen, but it's something to try while we find a solution with apache/php.

Comment: Here in this answer is something more logical described: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154182/916000 Try running your script with console.

Comment: What you can do is first open explorer (f4 -> address) and login from there. I was too getting this error, I used this approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431658/apache-network-drive-alias

Comment: Thanks for all answers. The final solution for me is https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944044/382854